# How can I convert PascalCase to split words?

Tags: c#

I have variables containing text such as:

```
ShowSummary
ShowDetails
AccountDetails
```

Is there a simple way function / method in C# that I can apply to these variables to yield:

```
"Show Summary"
"Show Details"
"Account Details"
```

I was wondering about an extension method but I've never coded one and I am not sure where to start.

Comment: `CameCase` is not a camel case! `camelCase` is.

Comment: Ashok has a good reply.  Please note the difference between camelCase and PascalCase (http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/csharpclasses_5.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the application I am currently working on, we have a delegate based split extension method. It looks like so:

```
public static string Split(this string target, Func<char, char, bool> shouldSplit, string splitFiller = " ")
{
    if (target == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

    if (shouldSplit == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("shouldSplit");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(splitFiller))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("splitFiller");

    int targetLength = target.Length;

    // We know the resulting string is going to be atleast the length of target
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(targetLength);

    result.Append(target[0]);

    // Loop from the second character to the last character.
    for (int i = 1; i < targetLength; ++i)
    {
        char firstChar = target[i - 1];
        char secondChar = target[i];

        if (shouldSplit(firstChar, secondChar))
        {
            // If a split should be performed add in the filler
            result.Append(splitFiller);
        }

        result.Append(secondChar);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Then it is could be used as follows:

```
string showSummary = "ShowSummary";
string spacedString = showSummary.Split((c1, c2) => Char.IsLower(c1) && Char.IsUpper(c2));
```

This allows you to split on any conditions between two `char`s, and insert a filler of your choice (default of a space).

Answer (score 6):

See this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/09/27/426087.aspx) by Jon Galloway and one by [Phil](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/09/24/splitting-pascalcamel-cased-strings.aspx)

Comment: I prefer Jon's one-line regex solution.

Comment: Answers which only contain links should be avoided, the link to Phil's solution is dead.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to iterate through each character within the string. Check if the character is upper case. If so, insert a space character before it. Otherwise, move onto the next character.

Also, ideally start from the second character so that a space would not be inserted before the first character.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var word = "AccountDetails";
word = string.Join(string.Empty,word
    .Select(c => new string(c, 1)).Select(c => c[0] < 'Z' ? " " + c : c)).Trim();
```